# Visual Studio 2013 IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I cannot use VS2013 due to the fact that the "Visual Studio Development Server" option is missing.  You can only use IIS Express, or an external host.  When I use IIS Express, I get one of several errors when I launch a website with F5.

1. Failed to register URL "" for site "" application "/". Error description: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0x800700b7)
2. Cannot process request because the process (8204) has exited.

Neither of them make sense.  I tried deleting all the configured sites in the IIS express config.  I tried reinstalling IIS Express, Visual Studio.  I don't see how the first error can occur.  In all the demos I've seen, you can just hit F5 in VS and it works.  This isn't the case here.

Comment: When it is really that weird, try to disable your antivirus software for a short while to test if that's the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Project in your solution and pick Properties.

Select web on the left side.

Choose IIS Express

Enter Project url

example:

```
https://localhost:44300
```

or you could check 'Override application root url' and type url like above

Comment: Yeah I've done that several times using several different ports.  This didn't help.  The more times I changed it, the more ports were used up.  Even if I change it to a new port, the very first time after that when I debug, it says the new port is already taken